# How to hide additional information given be matplotlib in html output in R-markdown?

Tags: python, matplotlib, r-markdown

I wrote a simple matplotlib plotting function in r-markdown

````
```{python}
Sw = np.arange(0.2, 0.9, 0.01)
Fw= np.arange(0.2, 0.9, 0.01)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
plt.plot(Sw, Fw, 'b-', )
plt.xlim([0,1])
plt.ylim([0,1])
plt.show()
```
````

in the html output this is showing as

```
Sw = np.arange(0.2, 0.9, 0.01)
Fw= np.arange(0.2, 0.9, 0.01)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
plt.plot(Sw, Fw, 'b-', )
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0000000064D82910>]
plt.xlim([0,1])
(0.0, 1.0)
plt.ylim([0,1])
(0.0, 1.0)
plt.show()
```

plots are showing fine. but i want to remove these extra information like `(0.0, 1.0)` after `plt.xlim()` and `plt.ylim()` and `[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0000000064D82910>]` after `plt.plot()`.

Any idea how to remove these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `results = "hide"` in python script indicator.

````
```{python, results = "hide"}
Sw = np.arange(0.2, 0.9, 0.01)
Fw= np.arange(0.2, 0.9, 0.01)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
plt.plot(Sw, Fw, 'b-', )
plt.xlim([0,1])
plt.ylim([0,1])
plt.show()
```
````

This just disables text output, It will still show plots.

You can learn more about this [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/hide-one.html)